# Map a matrix of integers to and image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Hi i'm having trouble converting a matrix to an image. I'm working on a procedural content generated 'world map' and i'm trying to display the matrix with nice colors.

I have an array that looks similar to this array below:

```py
world_map = [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, ],
             [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, ],
             [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, ],
             [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, ],
             [2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, ],
             [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ],
             [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, ],
             [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, ],
             [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, ],
             [2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, ]]
```

What i would like to do is convert this matrix to resemble and image by mapping the the values 1, 2 and 3 to some RGB values i picked with this lookup table:

```py
color_map = {
     1: [50, 64, 168],
     2: [70, 156, 44],
     3: [176, 167, 99],
}
```

I have tried mapping every value with the python `map` function and I have tried to vectorize a mapping function like this `np.vectorize(lambda c: color_map[c])(world_map)` but that resulted in an error. Does anyone know the proper way to map this matrix to an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
world_map = np.array(world_map)
img = np.empty(tuple(list(world_map.shape) + [3]))
img[world_map==1] = [50, 64, 168]
img[world_map==2] = [70, 156, 44]
img[world_map==3] = [176, 167, 99]
```